# Find which program caused a core dump file

Tags: debugging

I've been going through intense program/package installation recently, so I can't tell for sure which of the newly installed programs (or old programs) caused the appearance of a `core` file in my home folder. It's a server, so I better find out any possible sources of instability on the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it turned out there was a more straightforward way of identifying a misbehaved program using the `file` utility:

```
$ file core
core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'sqlplus'
```

So `sqlplus` in the example above would be the main suspect.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set the name of the core dump file to contain the PID and name of the process that caused the core dump using:

```
echo "core-%p-%e" | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

here is an example of it working:

```
./example 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ls core*
core-4170-example
```

See `man 5 core` for more details of how to use the core_pattern interface.

Comment: The filename format doesn't seem to to stick from one boot to another.

Comment: Indeed, it is a run time kernel setting. One needs to set it on each reboot.  You could add the command to /etc/rc.local for example, and since this is run with root privilege you just need to add the following line in /etc/rc.local:  echo "core-%p-%e" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern