# A big core dump appeared in my home folder - what is it and how can I delete it?

Tags: files

A large x-core file with name `core` appeared in my home directory. I don't know what it is and what to do with it.

I can't upload the core dump because when I tried to copy it somewhere, I couldn't even open it because it is so big.

I'd still appreciate finding out what this file is, and whether I can delete it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Core files are essentially low-level crash dumps; by default, the shell doesn't allow them to be written (by setting a 0 byte limit on their size `ulimit -c 0`) because they're rarely useful for end users. You can see what the limit is currently set to by typing `ulimit -c` in the bash shell.

You should be able to get information about what program caused the dump using the `file` command, as described in this previous answer [Find which program caused a core dump file](https://askubuntu.com/a/215010/178692) or if you have the GNU debugger installed on your system, by running `gdb -c core`.

Unless you are interested in debugging the crash further, you can simply delete the file using `rm core`.

If you're not actively compiling / debugging executable programs you may want to set the core ulimit back to its default value to stop such files getting generated.