# How to analyze an old /core file?

Tags: kernel, debugging

I found this old `core` file in my root directory from June:

```
$ ll /core
-rw------- 1 root root 46215168 Jun 20 16:16 /core

$ sudo file /core 
/core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :1 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -noliste'
```

How can I find out what application's crash produced this core dump? Is it from `Xorg` or from `lightdm` as suggested by the `file` output or may it be something else? What other meaningful information can I get from analyzing it and how would I do that?

Update:

```
$ sudo gdb -c /core
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
[some lines regarding copyright, license and manuals omitted...]
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[New LWP 6453]
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :1 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -noliste'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f14feb55418 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: You may be able to get more info using `gdb -c core` - see [A big core dump appeared in my home folder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/800416/a-big-core-dump-appeared-in-my-home-folder/800446#800446)

Comment: @steeldriver Updated with the output of `gdb`. So what exactly does that tell me?

Comment: Both `file` and `gdb` tell you that the program that died with a `SIGABRT`(see `man 7 signal`) was `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg`, which was called with these parameters: `-core :1 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten`. Start with `man 5 core`. `gdb` is of most use when one has the object (`*.o`) and source (`*.c`) files available.

Comment: @ByteCommander Did you figured out what is the cause of creating this core files ? I have got it after every shutdown

Comment: @EdiD You see the command that was responsible for the core dump when you analyse it with `file /core` and check the string inside single quotes in the end, `..., from '<COMMAND>'`. Probably it's something different for you than it was for me.

Comment: @ByteCommander output of  `file /core` is identical. I observed that core files are dumped while powering off with `poweroff` command and are not dumped when using gui shutdown (nothing in journal about this)