# Unknown file named "core" in /

Tags: 14.04, permissions, security, .desktop

Today I was searching for a file in my system and found a file in directory `/`

```
File Attributes:
Name: core
Size: 19MBs
Type: Unknown (I tried to cat the file)
Location: /
```

Permissions:

```
-rw-------   1 root root 19529728 Aug 30 11:41 core
```

I also tried to check if that file is used by any of the process using

```
fuser core
```

but that returned nothing.

Tried file command to check more about file

> file core

Output:

> core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style,
>   from '/sbin/init splash'

# Tried binwalk command to check the file, Below is the output.

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ELF, 64-bit LSB core file AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
12288         0x3000          ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
172048        0x2A010         Unix path: /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts
185792        0x2D5C0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/acpid.path
188592        0x2E0B0         Unix path: /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
196634        0x3001A         Unix path: /wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
205392        0x32250         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/plymouth-quit-wait.service
205888        0x32440         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d/debian.conf
218640        0x35610         Unix path: /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS20
232096        0x38AA0         Unix path: /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
285344        0x45AA0         Unix path: /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0
308998        0x4B706         Unix path: /0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
317552        0x4D870         Unix path: /run/systemd/generator.late/ondemand.service
322816        0x4ED00         Unix path: /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS21
335632        0x51F10         Unix path: /dev/disk/by-uuid/f9bb92ed-eebb-4b3f-92ca-568ffe4c0165
369264        0x5A270         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-resolvconf-update.path
394992        0x606F0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/failsafe-graphical.target
411856        0x648D0         Unix path: /proc/sys/fs/mqueue
414960        0x654F0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/rescue.target
419088        0x66510         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/getty-static.service
429568        0x68E00         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-ask-password-wall.path
451088        0x6E210         Unix path: /run/systemd/netif/state
461072        0x70910         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/virtlogd.service
469559        0x72A37         Unix path: /www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt
469670        0x72AA6         Unix path: /www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
469776        0x72B10         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/sys-kernel-config.mount
479584        0x75160         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/syslog.socket
483472        0x76090         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/cups.socket
500368        0x7A290         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd-control.socket
507900        0x7BFFC         Unix path: /freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ssh_2eservice
520960        0x7F300         Unix path: /usr/lib/snapd/snapd.core-fixup.sh
522704        0x7F9D0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service
529008        0x81270         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/rtkit-daemon.service
534512        0x827F0         Unix path: /run/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/50-After-systemd-logind\x2eservice.conf
538128        0x83610         Unix path: /run/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/50-After-systemd-user-sessions\x2eservice.conf
574000        0x8C230         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-binfmt.service
583472        0x8E730         Unix path: /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
584848        0x8EC90         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/emergency.target
590528        0x902C0         Unix path: /run/systemd/generator.late/irqbalance.service
602384        0x93110         Unix path: /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS16
630352        0x99E50         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service
642656        0x9CE60         Unix path: /var/run/libvirt/virtlockd-sock
653312        0x9F800         Unix path: /usr/lib/snapd/system-shutdown
661456        0xA17D0         Unix path: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0_WXJ1A17A3A8N-part5
672336        0xA4250         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/cgproxy.service
674608        0xA4B30         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/snapd.autoimport.service
681680        0xA66D0         Unix path: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2dnetworkd_2dresolvconf_2dupdate_2epath
691056        0xA8B70         Unix path: /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS8
702838        0xAB976         Unix path: /system.slice/libvirt-guests.service/control/cgroup.procs
704464        0xABFD0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service
716400        0xAEE70         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/whoopsie.service
719760        0xAFB90         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service
728096        0xB1C20         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journal-flush.service
747552        0xB6820         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/anacron.service
754152        0xB81E8         Unix path: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ssh_2eservice
758608        0xB9350         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/snapd.system-shutdown.service
767632        0xBB690         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/cups.service
780960        0xBEAA0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-ask-password-console.service
787952        0xC05F0         Unix path: /var/lib/systemd/timers/stamp-apt-daily.timer
805840        0xC4BD0         Unix path: /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS1
824528        0xC94D0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/polkitd.service
829184        0xCA700         Unix path: /var/run/libvirt/virtlockd-sock
852640        0xD02A0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service
920192        0xE0A80         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf
926768        0xE2430         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-remount-fs.service
928678        0xE2BA6         Unix path: /www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
935698        0xE4712         Unix path: /var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock
941280        0xE5CE0         Unix path: /run/user/1000/gvfs
951776        0xE85E0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path
965344        0xEBAE0         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/network-pre.target
977232        0xEE950         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target
978448        0xEEE10         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/acpid.service
997168        0xF3730         Unix path: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/job
1000144       0xF42D0         Unix path: /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
1009960       0xF6928         Unix path: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/upstart_2eservice
1011488       0xF6F20         Unix path: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit
1015160       0xF7D78         Unix path: /usr/lib/snapd/system-shutdown /run/initramfs/shutdown
1023504       0xF9E10         Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/-.slice
1034922       0xFCAAA         Unix path: /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
1038094       0xFD70E         Unix path: /systemd/system.slice/virtualbox.service/control/cgroup.procs
1048768       0x1000C0        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/alsa-state.service
1055520       0x101B20        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target
1067416       0x104998        Unix path: /org/freedesktop/DBus/Lo
1072032       0x105BA0        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/emergency.service
1112368       0x10F930        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/final.target
1116930       0x110B02        Unix path: /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
1125248       0x112B80        Unix path: /var/cache/cups/org.cups.cupsd
1192416       0x1231E0        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-resolvconf-update.service
1224416       0x12AEE0        Unix path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/virbr0
1257440       0x132FE0        Unix path: /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS26
1270528       0x136300        Unix path: /run/systemd/system/session-c2.scope.d/50-TasksMax.conf
1296392       0x13C808        Unix path: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2djournald_2ddev_2dlog_2esocket
1313008       0x1408F0        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service
1316048       0x1414D0        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/cgmanager.service
1329440       0x144920        Unix path: /var/run/cups/cups.sock
1333264       0x145810        Unix path: /var/lib/systemd/timers
1341872       0x1479B0        Unix path: /var/lib/systemd/random-seed
1347936       0x149160        Unix path: /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
1355136       0x14AD80        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/colord.service
1370976       0x14EB60        Unix path: /usr/local/lib/modules-load.d
1380098       0x150F02        Unix path: /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
1390016       0x1535C0        Unix path: /var/lib/systemd/timers
1396056       0x154D58        Unix path: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ssh_2eservice
1397984       0x1554E0        Unix path: /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part5
1403328       0x1569C0        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target
1403872       0x156BE0        Unix path: /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part5
1418816       0x15A640        Unix path: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-fsck-root.service
1452056       0x162818        Unix path: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ssh_2eservice
1615352       0x18A5F8        Unix path: /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
18935808      0x120F000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
18948096      0x1212000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
18972672      0x1218000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
18984960      0x121B000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
18997248      0x121E000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux)
19042304      0x1229000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19070976      0x1230000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19087360      0x1234000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19099648      0x1237000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19111936      0x123A000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19165184      0x1247000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19177472      0x124A000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19267584      0x1260000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19279872      0x1263000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19292160      0x1266000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19312640      0x126B000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19314167      0x126B5F7       mcrypt 2.2 encrypted data, algorithm: blowfish-448, mode: CBC, keymode: 8bit
19517440      0x129D000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
19518576      0x129D470       Unix path: /build/linux-hVVhWi/linux-4.4.0/arch/x86/entry/vdso/vclock_gettime.c
```

I have not added this file manually. I don't know how that file was created on the system. Is my system infected or does Ubuntu write these kinds of files automatically?

How can I check how that file was created & what that file is doing there?

Comment: Related: [A big core dump appeared in my home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800416/a-big-core-dump-appeared-in-my-home-folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

core files are created when an application crashes. A programmer can then find out how it crashed by using gdb.

Comment: How can I check that dump is created by what process or application?
Can you please share an example of gdb?

Comment: @AnkitArora The `file` command told you that already: `from '/sbin/init splash'`. It's also quite difficult for the untrained eye to get any more information that that with `gdb`, IMHO.

Comment: Read `man 5 core` or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/core.5.html and all will become clear.