# What is ~/core and why does it use ~2gbs of space?

Tags: files, filesystem

I have recently noticed that my Ubuntu system has been slowly filling up a file called `~/core`

```
-rw-------  1 tom  tom  2.4G Feb  1 18:08 core
```

It has recently reached 2.4G in size.

It contains many lines like this:

```
��9��6����6�I��6�Cu���~I:��e���x86_64/snap/pycharm-professional/179/jbr/bin/java-classpath/snap/pycharm-professional/179/lib/bootstrap.jar:/snap/pycharm-professional/179/lib/extensions.jar:/snap/pycharm-professional/179/lib/util.jar:/snap/pycharm-professional/179/lib/jdom.jar:/snap/pycharm-professional/179/lib/log4j.jar:/snap/pycharm-professional/179/lib/trove4j.jar:/snap/pycharm-professional/179/lib/jna.jar-Xms128m-Xmx1995m-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50-ea-XX:CICompilerCount=2-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off-
```

I can't seem to find any information about this file online.

Is it safe to delete this file or symlink it to /dev/null?

Comment: You should be able to find more information using `file ~/core` and/or `gdb -c ~/core`. See for example [A big core dump appeared in my home folder - what is it and how can I delete it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800416/a-big-core-dump-appeared-in-my-home-folder-what-is-it-and-how-can-i-delete-it)

Comment: Thanks! If you create an answer I will mark it solved